# Why is there a warning for Vue's provide and inject feature?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am thinking of using Vue's new provide/inject feature in a project, however in the official Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject) it gives this warning:

> provide and inject are primarily provided for advanced plugin / component library use cases. It is NOT recommended to use them in generic application code.

However, the docs do not give a reason why.  What is the danger of using provide and inject in "generic application code" and not in "advanced plugin / component library use cases"?

In the example code:

```
// parent component providing 'foo'
var Provider = {
  provide: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  // ...
}

// child component injecting 'foo'
var Child = {
  inject: ['foo'],
  created () {
    console.log(this.foo) // => "bar"
  }
  // ...
}
```

The benefit as I understand it is that if you have multiple nested children components, you can skip passing props down each nested child and just "receive" the injected value directly in a grandchild component, for example.

You can even make the injected value reactive if you bypass the default behavior of being non-reactive "if you pass down an observed object," but here a warning would make sense to me since you'd have a reactive variable spanning across nested components, where data isn't supposed to get passed up that way, so tracking changes might get more confusing if reactive objects are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the style guide: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Implicit-parent-child-communication-use-with-caution

> Props and events should be preferred for parent-child component communication, instead of this.$parent or mutating props.
>
> An ideal Vue application is props down, events up. However, there are edge cases where prop mutation or this.$parent can simplify two components that are already deeply coupled.
>
> The problem is, there are also many simple cases where these patterns may offer convenience. Beware: do not be seduced into trading simplicity (being able to understand the flow of your state) for short-term convenience (writing less code).

In this particular case you would essentially be mutating props with `inject`. You will want to pay careful attention to the fact that using `provide` / `inject` in a standard application does not following the canonical approach. If you want to map state to a component hierarchy [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) would be the preferred option.

Comment: thanks.  one problem with Vuex in this case is if you have multiple parent components on the same page, firing an event from a child of the parent gets picked up by both parent components.